Update deep learning models to memory every day with Uvicorn FastAPI without reloading
I have a FastAPI backend that needs to load new deep learning models everyday to memory. Models loads for the first time when FastAPI starts or force reload.
I have a class Predict and an endpoint to get data models info (mock code):
controller.py
def model_init():
    # vectors = <some code>
    # labels = <some code>
    return vectors, labels

def update(date):
    # <some code to get new models from server by date>
    return vectors, labels

class Predict:
    def __init__(self, vectors, labels) -> None:
        self.vectors = vectors
        self.labels = labels

        self.vectors, self.labels = model_init()

    def updateVectors(self, new_vector):
        self.vectors = new_vector

    def updateLabels(self, new_label):
        self.labels = new_label
    
    def process(self, data):
        print("Using models with vectors length = ", len(vectors), ", labels length = ", len(labels))
        # some code using self.vectors, self.labels
        # response = <something>
        return response

view.py
from controller import model_init
from datetime import datetime

vectors, labels = model_init()
predict = Predict(vectors, labels)

@router.get("/info")
async def get_info():
    response = {
        "vectors": len(vectors),
        "labels": len(labels),
        "date": datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
    }
    return {"info": response}

@router.post("/predict")
async def predictor(data):
    try:
        response = predict.process(data)
        return {"result": response}

    except PredictExceptionError as e:
        raise e

Suppose that, today I start Uvicorn FastAPI backend (uvicorn main:app --reload), after waiting for models first loaded to memory, I run /info endpoint. Result is len(vectors) = 1000000, and len(labels) = 1000.
What I am expecting is, when running /info endpoint again tomorrow, it returns len(vectors) = 2000000, and len(labels) = 2000. Also, when running /predict endpoint, new models have to load to memory without reloading FastAPI.
Any methods or approaches to update models to memory?

Use something like APScheduler: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/ to run a task every 24 hours that reloads the model? (i.e. loads the model and replaces the predict reference).

or how about background tasks fastapi? google it)
